# Выпить "чая" или выпить "чаю"?

Tags: падежи, окончания

Как правильно: "выпить чая" или "выпить чаю"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В русском языке правомерны оба варианта.

Answer (score 6):

Считаю вариант "выпить чаю" не только допустимым (разговорным), но и более правильным в  определенном контексте. Розенталю не противоречу. Он, если внимательно вчитаться, говорит, что форме партитива присущ разговорный оттенок (т.к. в разговорной речи это предпочтительно), но не отрицает употребление и в остальных стилях, включая книжный.

Тут вот какая штука намечается.
По многочисленным мнениям в Интернете полагаю, что "выпить чаю" - это некоторое неточно заданное или неопределенное количество. "Выпить чая" - именно чая, не кипятка и не пива.
Мнение субъективное, но я его внутренне вполне разделяю.

Answer (score 6):

Вот вам ответ. Один из падежей, которому сегодня не учат.

"**Количественно-отделительный** падеж является разновидностью родительного, в том смысле, что он отвечает на его же вопросы и указывает на некоторые из его функций. Иногда его можно легко заменить родительным, но иногда это будет звучать коряво. Например, вам предложить чашку (кого? чего?) чая или (кого? чего?) чаю?
Обратите внимание, что из классических шести падежей форма «чаю» подпадает под дательный падеж (кому? чему?), но здесь она отвечает на вопрос родительного (кого? чего?). Некоторые скажут, что форма «чаю» звучит как-то архаично, по-деревенски. Не уверен, что это правда; я бы скорее сказал «чаю», чем «чая», либо вообще бы переформулировал предложение так, чтобы использовать винительный падеж («Чай будете?»).
Вот другой пример: «задать жару». По-деревенски? Пожалуй, нет. А вариант «задать жара» режет слух. Ещё примеры: «налить соку», «прибавить ходу»".

[**Хитрые падежи русского языка**](http://ilyabirman.ru/meanwhile/2006/10/01/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Вариант *выпить чаю* более употребим в разговорной речи.

*Выпить чая* — стилистически нейтральный, общеупотребительный вариант.

Answer (score 3):

Согласна с предыдущим замечанием: окончание -ю для разговорной речи.

Answer (score 3):

Окончание **-ю** указывает на количественное значение, обозначает часть целого.
***Выпить чаю*** — допустимо, хотя и имеет разговорный оттенок, ***вкус чаю*** — неправильно.

Статья из справочника Розенталя по этому поводу:
[§152. Окончания родительного падежа единственного числа существительных мужского рода -а(-я) – -у(-ю)](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_07)

Comment: Ссылка сбилась немного. Вот более точная ссылка, на параграф: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#з_07

Answer (score 1):

Из правил письма: Вариантное окончание У/Ю  **для существительных м.р. в Р.п.,** наряду с основным окончанием А/Я,  используется в  ВЕЩЕСТВЕННЫХ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫХ  при указании на часть или количество, в том числе со словами ОТРИЦАНИЯ при отсутствии количества: выпить чаю (или чая), чашка чая (или чаю), нет сахара или сахару.

Хочется обратить внимание, что окончание У/Ю используется для сущ. м.р. 2-го скл. и **совпадает с окончанием Д.п.** А основное значение Д.п. - это  направленность, причем предмет в Д.п. выступает в роли **адресата или ориентира.** Если сравнить с В.п., то предмет в форме В.п. полностью охвачен действием, а предмет в Д.п. только сопричастен ему (изучать грамоту - учиться грамоте).

**Тогда (только в качестве версии):** **выпил весь чай (В.п.), выпил чая (партитивный Р.п. с указанием части предмета) и выпил чаю (с указанием только самого напитка).**

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые существительные мужского рода, которые по природе своей не поддаются счёту, в родительном падеже единственного числа могут иметь окончания -у (-ю), если количество их всё же ограничивается.
Например: стакан соку (чаю, квасу), килограмм сахару, бутылка квасу (соку), тарелка супу; но плантации чая, производство сахара (кваса).

Comment: "Нос" - счету поддается? *Кровь из носу. Вышел из лесу. С глазу долой*.   Вы правильно в общем-то пишете, но уж очень примитивные формулировки даете, это опасно недопониманием.

Answer (score 0):

Почти верно выше. Лучше всего это чувствуется стилистически в вопросительной форме:

Хотите чаю? (Я чай уже заварил, и он уже есть, и я предлагаю некоторое количество его вам — не зря форма "чаю" это количественно-отделительный падеж ранее был)

Хотите чая? (В общем, я предлагаю вам чай, но на такой вопрос, в отличие от первого, уместно ответить "нет, спасибо, лучше кофе" или "да, зеленого, если можно". В первом же варианте выбора не даю.)

Хотите соку? (Я тут, значит, вчера яблочки в саду собрал и сок из них сделал. Яблочный. И предлагаю *отделить* некоторое *количество* этого соку Вам. Тот же вопрос можно задать, скажем, наливая сок себе.)

Хотите сока? (А может, молока или чая?)

Из современных языков нечто подобное можно увидеть в английском языке:
Хотите чаю? - Would you like some tea?
Хотите чая? - Would you like tea (хотя в английском так очень редко говорят)?
Даже гугл переводчик знает разницу между "чая" и "чаю".

Если речь идет о растении "чай" или о самих сухих листьях, то в этом случае только "чая": "Взвесьте мне 100 граммов черного чая, пожалуйста", поскольку количество этого чая можно померить.

Comment: Не знает гугл-переводчик разницы между "чаю" и "чая". *...но на такой вопрос, в отличие от первого, уместно ответить "нет, спасибо, лучше кофе" или "да, зеленого, если можно".* Первый тоже можно перефразировать: "Хотите чаю или кофе/квасу?". Насчёт сухого чая (чаю) тоже не соглашусь. Это Ваши домыслы.

Answer (score 0):

Хотя "чая" не является неверным,  в повседневной речи "чаю" употребляется куда чаще. Вот пример из стихов Сергея Гандлевского:

Поговорим, покурим, выпьем чаю.
  Пора ложиться. Мне, наверняка,
  Опять приснится хмурая, большая,
  Наверное, великая река.

Обратите внимание, что у автора была возможность использовать "чая" ради более точной рифмы. Но он предпочёл этой возможностью не воспользоваться.

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется, что Розенталь все-таки говорил о родительном падеже "выпить кружку чая", так как выпить чая или чаю неверно стилистически. Выпить можно кого/что винительный падеж - чай. "Я выпил чай", "я выпил чашку чая". 
Чашку чаю - это вообще разговорный устаревший язык.

Answer (score -1):

В самом русском языке, самим русским языком обозначено:

- "хотите чай?" — стало быть, предлагается именно тот напиток, который является чаем;
- "хотите чаю?" — стало быть, предлагается некоторое количество напитка, который называется чаем;
- "хотите чая?" — стало быть, предлагается выбрать из нескольких напитков чая именно тот, который вам по вкусу (зеленый, чёрный, с мятой и т. д.)

...Внимательнее! "В самом русском языке" — написано не зря. Потому что в самом русском языке "чай", "чаю" и "чая" должны восприниматься именно так, как я пояснил. Но дело в том, что человек, употребляющий слова: "чай", "чаю", "чая", может иметь в виду под словом "чай" — количество (то есть "чаю") либо выбор марки (то есть "чая"); может иметь в виду под "чаю" — сам напиток (то есть "чай) либо выбор марки (то есть "чая"); может иметь в виду под "чая" — сам напиток (то есть "чай) либо количество (то есть "чаю"). В русском языке присутствует взаимозаменяемость слов.

Comment: Думаю, Вам не удастся распространить здесь своё личное понимание для "хотите чая?". Или Вы сможете подтвердить его какими-то правилами? Может, цитатами из литературы? Чем-то ещё? Подозреваю, что не сможете и что ни один носитель языка с Вами не согласится.

Comment: Спасибо, но неубедительно.

Comment: значения слов уже подтверждают мою правоту:
1) чай - (значение в имен.падеже) - определённый напиток; выбор из нескольких разных напитков;
2) чаю - (значение в род.пад) - количественное;
3) чая - (значение в род.пад) - выбор из названий одного, определенного напитка одного из его сортов.

Comment: Проверьте Вашу "правоту" на значениях других слов в родительном падеже (квас, пиво, лимонад, вода и т. д.).

Comment: квас, квасу, кваса... пиво, пива, пива... лимонад, лимонаду, лимонада... ***, воду, воды... мёд, мёду, мёда...проверил!