# Какие знаки должны стоять в названии главки книги?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

Мы знаем, что ***без роду без племени*** не требует знаков.

Автор хочет обыграть идиому, рассказывая о знатном происхождении юного кенийца, живущего в одиночку, и получилось:

> **Из рода, без племени...**

Поправить ли хотя бы на "из роду"?

Бороться ли с запятой? (Боюсь, её отсутствие сделает заголовок совсем уж невоспринимаемым.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше оставить: **из рода, без племени**

Так лучше видно, что устойчивый оборот изменен.

Частотность формы ***из рода*** значительно выше, чем ***из роду*** (748:34), при этом вариант ***из роду*** относится в основном к старой литературе.

Примеры: Да так, потому она была барыня настоящая, христианка… **из род**у тоже настоящего, хорошего, богатого. [А. Ф. Писемский. Люди сороковых годов (1869)]А ведь Феня-то все-таки своя кровь, **из роду-племени** не выкинешь. [Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Золото (1892)]

Answer (score 2):

В данном заголовке я бы оставил запятую и "из род**а**". Другие варианты:
"Не без роду, но без племени", "Из рода, **но** без племени".

Почему я бы оставил *у* только в случае "без роду"?

[Розенталь](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_07) приводит фразеологический оборот "без роду и племени" как пример употребления *у*, а [Sibylla](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/662/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E) пишет, что *у* характерно для отрицательных конструкций:

> Из правил письма: Вариантное окончание У/Ю для существительных м.р. в Р.п., наряду с основным окончанием А/Я, используется в ВЕЩЕСТВЕННЫХ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫХ при указании на часть или количество, в том числе со словами ОТРИЦАНИЯ при отсутствии количества: выпить чаю (или чая), чашка чая (или чаю), нет сахара или сахару.

У вас структура оборота нарушена, отрицание сменилось утверждением, поэтому  *а*: из род**а**.